# Converting Data Object to Int in Flex Mobile Project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5

I am developing a mobile project in Flash builder using flex 4.5. I am very new to flex, with some background in Obj-C.

Current Setup:

I am passing the text property of a text input component to a second view via navigator.pushview{view.Someview, data}

```
public function doSomething():void{
            navigator.pushView(Session_View, timeInput.text);
        }
```

This successfully passes the text I put into the textinput to the Session_View instance and I can display that text in a label in the mxml; however, I would like to take the text passed and convert it to an integer to use in my logic.

Within Action Script I have tried parseInt() function with no luck.
I have also tried to assign data to a variable in actionscript with no luck.

Does any flex ninja out there know what I am doing wrong or a best practices way to pass a simple string between views in flex mobile and then convert that string to an int?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both parseInt and casting to Number should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var intA:int;
            [Bindable]
            public var intB:int;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var s:String = "55";
                intA = parseInt(s);
                intB = Number(s);

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label text="{intA}" />
        <s:Label text="{intB}" />
        <s:Label text="{intA+intB}" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Edit: Override set data.

In the view that you are pushing you should be able to get at the variable from the `data` object.

```
var someInteger:int = data.integerProperty;
```

If you need to do something with that property every time data is pushed into the view, and not just the first time you should override the set data method.

```
public override function set data(value:Object):void{
    super.data = value;
    var someInteger:int = data.integerProperty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I need to reword my question. My problem is that when I try to pass an object from the navigator.pushView(view, dataobject), I can't figure out how to access the dataobject from actionscript. I can access {dataobject.property} from MXML easily, but I want to set a variable in the new view to the passed dataobjects property.

Comment: edited answer above on how to access the data that is pushed into the view.